# Getting type error while opening an uploaded sql file

Tags: python, django

I'm developing an application in python with django. User can upload a SQL file. I use fileField to get the file. But, it's not stored any where. I try to take it from request to process the file. While I'm trying to open the file, it gives an error. Request object which I try to take the uploaded file is also django designed object.

```
from mssql2postgresql.form import LoadForm

form = LoadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
    docFile = request.FILES['docFile']
    archivo = UploadedFile.name
    print 'este es el file', docFile
```

The given error is :

```
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, InMemoryUploadedFile found
```

Comment: Did you mean this? `print 'este es el file', archivo`

Answer (score 0):

Files stored in `request.FILES` are streams, so they can't be just casted to strings. To print file content, you must read it first:

```
docFile = request.FILES['docFile'].read()
```